# Sending a keystroke to Python subprocess without stdin-PIPE

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a Windows commandline app which prints an output to stdout and then waits indefinitely for a keystroke to end. I use a function like this to handle it:

```
def run_command_on_windows(command):
    """
    Run commandline program on Windows OS (current)
    :param command: command to run (string)
    :return: returns result of command
    """
    p = subprocess.Popen(['c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', '/c'] +   command.split(),
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = p.communicate()
    p.stdin.write('\n\n')
    rc = p.returncode

    return output.split('\r\n')
```

All would be easy if I could use 'stdin=subprocess.PIPE' in Popen, but I can't, since the app will crash instantly when I redirect stdin like that.

```
p.stdin.write('\n\n')
```

does not work, crashed with AttributeError.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Write a CMD script and invoke the command in there with I/O redirection. Try `echo | ...` to make the command end.

You can also try to close stdin so the command can't wait for a keypress: `... < nul:`

If that doesn't work, write a newline to a file and use `... < file`

If that also doesn't work, you will have to change the source of the program (it probably uses some special code to read the keyboard) or kill it with `p.terminate()`

Comment: The program will crash on any attempt to redirect stdin, the < nul: and < file won't work... it has some event handler that waits for the keystrokes.

probably will need change in the app code :(

Comment: or kill it. It's not nice but it's not a nice program :-)